# Convert vcf file to phylip format but getting error

Tags: python, linux

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vcf2phylip.py", line 502, in <module>
    main()
  File "vcf2phylip.py", line 217, in main
    sample_names = extract_sample_names(args.filename)
  File "vcf2phylip.py", line 73, in extract_sample_names
    for line in vcf:
  File "/home/moodley/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

python vcf2phylip.py -i angsd_new_vcf_with_OUTGROUP.vcf

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is gzip-compressed (the byte 0x8b on position 1 hints to that). So try to rename the file to angsd_new_vcf_with_OUTGROUP.vcf.**gz** and try again.

Comment: i tried it still the same i also tried to see what the problem might be by typing file and the vcf file this is what is coming up Blocked GNU Zip Format (BGZF; gzip compatible), block length 11903, what must i do here? unzip the file maybe ??

Comment: Ok, that underlines my thought with it being gzip-compressed. I think the library should automatically be able to read gzipped files when it has the correct file-extension, but apparently not. So yes you could try to unzip it yourself before reading it with the library.